# значение словосочетания "когда-нибудь"

Tags: стилистика

Добрый день!
Допустимо ли сказать: "Встретимся когда-нибудь в декабре", имея ввиду, что встреча произойдет в течении конкретного декабря, например в декабре текущего года?
Большое спасибо!

Comment: Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста. Я не вижу здесь альтернативы.

Answer (score 1):

"Когда-нибудь" отменяет сугубую конкретику декабря. Тогда уж -

***Встретимся как-нибудь в декабре...***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

*Сказать* — еще как допустимо. Что тут такого...

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем!

Было бы неправилно написать: "Встретимся когда-нибудь завтра" (В течении завтрашнего дня)?

Галина, Вы меня поняли правильно. Но ведь неопределённость же и есть.